# Axios Delete doest not work in react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, axios

```
export const deleteComment = (id) => {
  console.log("id", id);
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(
        `http://localhost:5000/comments/${id}`
      );
      console.log("response", response);
      dispatch(actions.DeleteCommentAction(id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

For some reasons, this code does not work. When i use this acton the `console.log("id",id)` is being executed, but `console.log` with response is not. I tested my route for deleting in Postman and everything works, does anyone know what is this happening?

Route for deleting, but as i said. It work, it some issue in React i guess:

```
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    Comment.findByIdAndDelete(id, function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        return res.send(error);
      }
      console.log(response);
      return res.send(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.send(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually forgot to add:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  deleteComment,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the network tab to see if the request was sent?

Can you share the component where you are invoking deleteComment?

And perhaps try to simplify and execute the deletion outside the deleteComment method, it might be you are not injecting the dispatch method into the anonymous function.

The cause could also related to redux. I guess you are not using a redux middleware to handle the asynchronous executions as you are waiting the deletion, which could be a possible scenario for the issue. And maybe you could consider adding one of those middlewares like [reduxk-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) for example.

Comment: It does not send the request in network tab.